# chart.js horzontalBar Stacked and Grouped - data not showing - a bug?

Tags: chart.js

can anyone help me understand why the first chart in this fiddle isn't showing correctly?. It should have two grouped horizontal stacks, but the two datasets assigned to the secondary X axis (x-axis-1) of the datasets are not showing.

https://jsfiddle.net/c2jtL7gz/5/

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "horizontalBar",
    data: {
            "datasets":[{
                    "label":"One",
                    "data":[100],
                    "stack":"Stack 0",
                    "backgroundColor":"green"
                    },{
                    "label":"Two",
                    "data":[200],
                    "stack":"Stack 0",
                    "backgroundColor":"orange"
                    },{
                    "label":"Three",
                    "data":[150],
                                            "stack":"Stack 1",
                    "xAxisID":"x-axis-1",
                    "backgroundColor":"lightgrey"
                    },{
                    "label":"Four",
                    "data":[300],
                    "stack":"Stack 1",
                    "xAxisID":"x-axis-1",
                    "backgroundColor":"darkgrey"}]},
    options: {

            scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            id: "x-axis-0",
                            },{
                            stacked: true,
                            id: "x-axis-1",
                            }],
                    yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            id: "y-axis-0",
                            }],
                    }
            }
    });
```

The second chart has the same configuration, but with minimal changes to make it a normal (vertical) bar chart, and it works exactly as expected.

Is this a bug in the library, or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! According to the docs it looks like the data structure for the horizontal bar chart is slightly different. You want data to look like:

```
data: {
        "labels": ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"],
        "datasets":[{
                "label": "First Dataset",
                "data":[100,200,150,300],
                "backgroundColor":["green","orange","lightgrey","darkgrey"]
        }]
},
```

I've attached a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c2jtL7gz/6/

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for having a look (and yes, that was my first post to SO), but your example doesn't fit the original problem, as it is not grouped with a secondary axis, and this is specific to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clarifying. Is this what you were thinking of? https://jsfiddle.net/c2jtL7gz/7/ I simply removed the `xAxisId` I think you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Unfortunately not - my use of xAxisId is correct, all that you've done there is to present both grouped data on the same axis, which is not the effect that I need. As per the second chart, "Stack 1" should be on a secondary axis.

I think this is a bug, and have reported it as such on the chart.js github page

Comment: Okay I finally understood your question. A picture of what you have in mind would help next time. I added `type: linear` and that seemed to do the trick. Results here: https://jsfiddle.net/c2jtL7gz/8/

Comment: I think you've found it! - it sounds like unexpected behaviour, but that sounds like it should work

Comment: They do specify it in their docs but I'll admit it's buried in the text: `When adding new axes, it is important to ensure that you specify the type of the new axes as default types are not used in this case.`